# Notation for the $\inf S$ with $S$ as a subset of extended reals.

Tags: real-analysis

I defined as set $S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \text{statement A is true for}\; x\}$. Then it is apparent that $S\subset \mathbb{R}$. But $S$ can be empty depending on the condition imposed on $x$. So I want to include extended real numbers - for example, $\inf S =\infty$, when $S=\emptyset$. Instead of spelling it out like this, is there a better way to denote the fact that $\inf$ is seek in the extended real line?

Comment: Depending on the audience, you may be good to just assume they know this without saying anything about it. Other than spelling it out, the only other thing I can think of is saying something like "We define $\inf:2^\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ by $\ldots$" (where $2^\mathbb{R}$ is my notation for the power set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is my notation for extended reals).

Comment: A common notation for $\Bbb R \cup \{\pm \infty\}$ is $\overline{\mathbb R}$

Comment: @jwhite Thank you. Your comment helps. I will use your notation with Ben Grossmann's suggestion for $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. If one of you would post it as the answer, I will accept it. Thank you both so much.